# React Native: Axios Network Error from several domain

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator, axios

I'm new on React, and trying to get data from my server. But the result is 'Network Error'. I've try to change domain to https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5, and still error. But when I try to request to https://www.google.com or https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json, the results is ok. I've opened site from my device browser, all site have no problem.

```
 axios.get(`https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5`)
                .then((result) => {
                    console.log(result.data);

            }).catch(error => {
                this.setState({error, loading: false, refreshing: false});
                console.log(error.message);
                console.log(error);

            });
```

Info:

- I'm using android emulator (NOX).
- Both of domain (my server & randomuser.me) use Cloudflare.

Error :

```
Error: Network Error
    at createError (C:\react-native\First\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:25)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (C:\react-native\First\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js:72)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (C:\react-native\First\node_modules\event-target-shim\lib\event-target.js:172)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (C:\react-native\First\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.…:580)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (C:\react-native\First\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.…:394)
    at C:\react-native\First\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.…:507
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (C:\react-native\First\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmi…:190)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (C:\react-native\First\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQu…:349)
    at C:\react-native\First\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQu…:106
    at MessageQueue.__guard (C:\react-native\First\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQu…:297)
```

I hope someone can help me or give me reference about this problem.

**UPDATE: Work on real device.**